# manipulation with PowerShell variables

Tags: powershell, variables

Is there any way to get output "bigString1bigString2bigString3" of following

```
$a = $null
$b = $null
$b = "bigString1" + $a + "bigString3"
$a = "bigString2"
#output needed
$b = "bigString1bigString2bigString3"
```

Strings `"bigString1" "bigString2" "bigString3"` can not repeat in the code as they make code messy.

CAN NOT assign "bigString1" and "bigString3" into **separate variables** as they can change, e.g. `$b = "bigString8" + $a + "bigString9"`

Also `$a` variable can change in the code later like `$a="bigString4"`  then I will need output `"bigString1bigString4bigString3"`

I know its not a standard situation, but is there any way by manipulating with variables to get required output?

Thanks

Comment: Swap line 3 and 4 and you're good to go

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I know about that, but Also $a variable can change in the code later like $a="bigString4"  then I will need output "bigString1bigString4bigString3"

Comment: So write a function: `function Get-BigString { "bigString1" + $a + "bigString3" }`

Comment: Use a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks): `$b = {"bigString1" + $a + "bigString3"}`. Then, `$a = $null; $b.Invoke()` returns `bigString1bigString3` and `$a = " any string "; $b.Invoke()` returns `bigString1 any string bigString3`…